# Not supporting NGSIv2 metadata in device provisioned attributes

Tags: json, fiware

We have used IoT agent -1.14.0 version from docker hub.
We have given the service and servicepath as follows
fiware-service:testiotagent
fiware-servicepath:/

Device registration payload :

```
{
"devices": [
{
"device_id":"Motion-10",
"entity_name":"urn:ngsi-ld:SENSOR:Motion-10",
"entity_type":"SENSOR",
"transport": "MQTT",
"attributes": [
{"object_id": "s", "name": "state", "type":"Text"},
{"object_id": "l", "name": "luminosity", "type":"Integer",
"metadata":{ "unitCode":{"type": "Text", "value" :"CAL"}
}
}
]
}
]
}
```

As per iotagent node lib version 2.12.0 ,IoT agent json -1.14.0 version should support the metadata in device provisioned attributes. But still facing issue.
When we try to provision the above device we are getting the below error:

```
{
"name": "WRONG_SYNTAX",
"message": "Wrong syntax in request: Errors found validating request."
}
```

I found that iotagent-node-lib have the schema to validate against device registration payload

https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/lib/templates/createDevice.json

In this json schema there is no metadata schema mentioned in attributes.

I have followed the below steps for metadata in Entity level:

I have removed the metadata in IoT agent
Updated the entity 'urn:ngsi-ld:SENSOR:Motion-10' as below

```
{
"id":"urn:ngsi-ld:SENSOR:Motion-10",
"type":"SENSOR",
"luminosity":{
"type":"Integer",
"value":"0",
"metadata":{ "unitCode":{"type": "Text", "value" :"CAL"}
}
}
```

Tried to send measurement and metadata got overriden and got the empty metadata

```
{
"id":"urn:ngsi-ld:SENSOR:Motion-10",
"type":"SENSOR",
"luminosity":{
"type":"Integer",
"value":"15",
"metadata":{}
}
}
```

Is it due to the fix given for issue 1788 in fiware-orion ,https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues?q=1788.
Need some qucik confirmation and help from Fiware experts to overcome this issue, it is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The templates checking a valid provisioning request currently does not accept the metadata attribute. There is an outstanding [PR](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/pull/870) for this. At the moment you would be better off defining the Entities with the `metadata` in a `config.js` file instead.

e.g.:

```
 iotAgentConfig = {
        contextBroker: {
            host: '192.168.1.1',
            port: '1026',
            ngsiVersion: 'v2'
        },
        server: {
            port: 4041
        },
        types: {
            'WeatherStation': {
                commands: [],
                type: 'WeatherStation',
                lazy: [],
                active: [
                    {
                        object_id: 'p',
                        name: 'pressure',
                        type: 'Hgmm'
                    },
                    {
                        object_id: 'h',
                        name: 'humidity',
                        type: 'Percentage',
                        entity_name: 'Higro2000',
                        entity_type: 'Higrometer',
                        metadata:{
                            unitCode:{
                                type: "Text", value :"Hgmm"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
    ....etc
```